# Closed form expression for integral involving modified Bessel function?

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

In my research, I have come across the following integral $\int_0^{\infty} x e^{-x^2}I_1(2xy)e^{-\alpha x} dx$ where $y\geq 0$ and $\alpha\geq 0$ are parameters, and $I_1$ is the modified Bessel function of order 1. Ideally I would like to know if there exists a closed form expression for this integral in terms of $y$ and $\alpha$.  I have checked Watson and I can't find it there (other than the case where $\alpha=0$), so I suspect that it is probably not known (at least classically). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find any closed form for
$$\int_0^{\infty} x e^{-x^2}I_1(2xy)e^{-\alpha x} dx$$ but we can do a few things;

$$x=\frac{t}{2 y}\implies I=\frac 1{4y^2}\exp\left(\frac{\alpha ^2}{4} \right)\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\left(\frac{t}{2 y}+\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)^2 \right)\,t\, I_1(t)\,dt$$

Now using
$$t\, I_1(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{-(2 n+1)} }{n! \, (n+1)!}\,t^{2( n+1)}$$
$$\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\left(\frac{t}{2 y}+\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)^2 \right)\,t^{2(n+1)}\,dt=e^{-\frac{\alpha ^2}{4}} y^{2 n+3}\, \Gamma (2 n+3)\,
   U\left(n+\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{\alpha ^2}{4}\right)$$ where appears Tricomi'sconfluent hypergeometric function.

All of this makes
$$\color{blue}{I=\frac{\alpha  y}{4 \sqrt{\pi }}\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (n+1)}\,\,y^{2n}\,\,U\left(n+2,\frac{3}{2},\frac{\alpha ^2}{4}\right)}$$

The summation seems to be converging without any problem. Trying for $y=\alpha=1$, the partial sums are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \sum_{n=0}^p \\
 0 & 0.159231 \\
 1 & 0.241763 \\
 2 & 0.267294 \\
 3 & 0.273057 \\
 4 & 0.274090 \\
 5 & 0.274243 \\
 6 & 0.274263 \\
 7 & 0.274265 \\
 8 & 0.274266
\end{array}
\right)$$

If $\alpha$ is small, we can use the expansion of Tricomi'sconfluent hypergeometric function and then

$$A_n=\frac{\alpha  y}{4 \sqrt{\pi }}  \frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (n+1)}\,\,y^{2n}\,\,U\left(n+2,\frac{3}{2},\frac{\alpha ^2}{4}\right)$$  will give
$$A_n=\frac{y^{2 n+1}}{2 \Gamma (n+1) }\Bigg[\frac{1}{\Gamma (n+2)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma \left(n+k+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{(2 k)!}\,\alpha^{2k}-\frac{1}{ (n+1)}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)_k}{(2 k-1)!}\,\alpha^{2k-1}\Bigg] $$

Now, consider
$$S_k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma \left(n+k+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma (n+1)\Gamma (n+2) }y^{2 n+1}$$
they all write
$$S_k=\sqrt{\pi }\,y\, e^{\frac{y^2}{2}} \Bigg[P_k(y^2) \,I_0\left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right)+Q_{k-1}(y^2) \,I_1\left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right)\Bigg]$$
where $P_i(u)$ and $Q_i(u)$ are polynomials of degree $i$ in $u$.

Similarly

$$T_k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+1)_k}{(n+1)\Gamma (n+1)} y^{2n+1}= y\,e^{y^2}\,R_{k-1}(y^2)$$

**Edit**

To avoid loosing this more than interesting comment from @Maxim

*If we expand $U$ into series, we get hypergeometric functions of two variables of order two, which are expressible in terms of the Horn functions. In this case we get the [Humbert series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series) $\Psi_2$:
$$\color{red}{I = \frac {y \sqrt \pi} 4  \Psi_2 {\left( \frac 3 2, 2, \frac 1 2; y^2, \frac {\alpha^2} 4 \right)} - \frac {\alpha y} 2  \Psi_2 {\left( 2, 2, \frac 3 2; y^2, \frac {\alpha^2} 4 \right)}}$$*

Comment: Always nice to see your answers. Cheers :)

Comment: @YuriyS. Be sure that, coming from you, this is much appreciated. Thanks and cheers :-)

Comment: @YuriyS. I think that it is better now.

Comment: If we expand $U$ into series, we get hypergeometric functions of two variables of order two, which are expressible in terms of the Horn functions. In this case we get the [Humbert series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series) $\Psi_2$:
$$I = \frac {y \sqrt \pi} 4
 \Psi_2 {\left( \frac 3 2, 2, \frac 1 2; y^2, \frac {\alpha^2} 4 \right)} -
\frac {\alpha y} 2
 \Psi_2 {\left( 2, 2, \frac 3 2; y^2, \frac {\alpha^2} 4 \right)}.$$

Comment: @Maxim. This is nice. Write an answer please. If you do not want, do you allow me to put and edit with this interesting result, quoting and citing you for sure.

Comment: Of course, please go ahead and add it to your answer.

Comment: @Maxim. Done. Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: That is great! Thank you for your help!